# Reverse text in div by line

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like to have the text reversed in a div for each line. So, for instance if the given text is:

```
apple orange banana
potato salad carrot
abcd efgh ijkl
```

I'd like to get:

```
ananab egnaro elppa
torrac dalas otatop
lkji hgfe dcba
```

Reversing the whole text won't work as it would flip also the top-down order of the text. So, all I want to achieve is to be able to read the text from right to left.

Is there any easy javascript / jquery solution for this?

```
style="direction: rtl"
```

is not a solution, I still need to read from left to right.

Thanks.

Comment: When you ask "is there any easy [JavaScript] / [jQuery] solution for this" did you mean to ask "is there an existing tool, or library I could use to do this?" If you did, then your question is off-topic as we don't link to external resources, libraries, books, or tools. If you meant to ask "how could I do this, using JavaScript or jQuery?" then you need to share your best attempt (add the (**relevant**) "*[mcve]*" code to the question), and also you should (re-) read the "*[ask]*" guidance.

Comment: *Is there any easy javascript solution?* It can be done in 3 lines, maybe less. But I'll have to defer to @DavidThomas comment in where's your attempt?

Comment: Are you saying that the text in the div may wrap in unpredictable places, and there are no explicit line breaks? Or are there line breaks inside the div's textContent?

Comment: Have you heard of `String.reverse()`?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/m85jbte2/

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Select each div inside the container
  $("#textContainer div").each(function() {
    // Get the text content of the div
    var text = $(this).text();

    // Reverse the text
    var reversedText = text.split('').reverse().join('');

    // Set the reversed text back to the div
    $(this).text(reversedText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="textContainer">
  <div>apple orange banana</div>
  <div>potato salad carrot</div>
  <div>abcd efgh ijkl</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What classifies this as ChatGPT answer?

Comment: Well. To be honest I just used VS code extension of HTML and JS scaffolding and then copied it over here that is why it showed the complete structure. I don't insist to remove your comment about it, but would like to keep it here to clear the misconceptions. 

For your 2nd point regarding "the first answer in a year and first JS answer" - Does this give an impression that the code has been AI generated? Sorry to say but the answer does not have anything to do with me not being active for a year.

Answer (score -1):

1. Clone the div, transform words to spans and split the text to lines.
2. Watch for the div resized and repeat the process (if needed).
3. To make lines stables wrap them in DIVs or add spaces (more complex).

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.style = $text.style.cssText;

const words = $text.textContent.match(/\S+/g);

div.innerHTML = words.map(word => `<span>${word}</span>`).join(' '); 

const resizer = new ResizeObserver(resize);
resizer.observe($text);

function resize(){
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.style.width = $text.offsetWidth + 'px';
  let top, line = [];
  const lines = [];

  [...div.children].forEach((span, idx) => {
    const spanTop = span.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    top ??= spanTop;
    if(spanTop > top){
      top = spanTop;
      lines.push(line);
      line = [words[idx]];
    } else line.push(words[idx]);
  });

  line.length && lines.push(line);
  $text.innerHTML = lines.map(line => '<div>' +  [...line.join(' ')].reverse().join('') + '</div>').join(' ');
  div.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="$text" style="width:100px;border: 1px solid gray;box-sizing: border-box;">
apple orange banana
potato salad carrot
abcd efgh ijkl
</div>
<label onclick="$text.style.width = '50px'"><input name="width" type="radio"  >50px</label>
<label onclick="$text.style.width = '100px'"><input name="width" type="radio" checked >100px</label>
<label onclick="$text.style.width = '150px'"><input name="width" type="radio"  >150px</label>
```

Comment: Perhaps a bit over the top for a noob?

Comment: @mplungjan cannot be much simpler if we need to split free text inside a div

Comment: Not my downvote, but yeah, too much code in my opinion